# Call an IBM DB2 Stored Procedure in SSIS with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, db2, oledb, ssis

My question pertains to this statement:

*The IBM OLE DB DB2 provider and Microsoft OLE DB DB2 provider do not support using an SQL command that calls a stored procedure. When this kind of command is used, the OLE DB source cannot create the column metadata and, as a result, the data flow components that follow the OLE DB source in the data flow have no column data available and the execution of the data flow fails.*

[OLE DB Source Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141696.aspx)

My Scenario:
1. I have a IBM DB2 Stored Procedure that has 2 input parameters. 
   This stored procedure returns a multi-row result-set.
2. I intend to use the data returned by this stored procedure for populating the columns in a SQL Server table. While some columns map directly, some of the columns that need to be populated in SQL Server table are to be derived from the data returned by the IBM DB2 stored procedure.
3. I am using the IBM DB2 OLEDB Provider.

Given the limitation I've mentioned in the beginning of the question, I would like to know if my objective can still be achieved ? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I would alter the DB2 SP to send it's results to permanent DB2 tables.  Then I would point SSIS at those tables.